# Setting value of DataGridComboBoxColumn not reflected in the UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataview that contains a DataGridComboBoxColumn for one value. I set the options with a list of strings, and then loop through the rows to set the initial values of this column. I can debug after looping through and the value is there as I expect it, but in the UI my combo box is still empty. Am I missing something that will set the value in the UI or what am I doing wrong?

```
    private void PrepareList() {
        var dt = new DataTable {
            Columns = {
                new DataColumn("Style Number"),
                new DataColumn("Description"),
                new DataColumn("Department"),
            }
        };

        foreach (var orderEntity in _fullList) {
            foreach (var line in orderEntity.Lines) {
                dt.Rows.Add(line.VendorItemNumber, line.Description, line.Department);
            }
        }

        var view = new DataView(dt) {Sort = "Style Number asc"};
        var distinct = view.ToTable(true, "Style Number", "Description");

        dataGrid.DataSource = distinct;

        var repo = new DepartmentRepository();
        var departments = repo.GetDepartmentList();

        var vendor = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn {
            DataSource = departments,
            ValueType = typeof(string),
            HeaderText = @"Department",
            Name = "Department",
            DataPropertyName = "Department"
        };

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(vendor);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows) {
            var dtRow = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => 
                    r["Style Number"].ToString() == row.Cells["Style Number"].Value.ToString());

            var dept = dtRow == null ? "" : departments.FirstOrDefault(
                s => s.StartsWith(dtRow["Department"].ToString()));

            row.Cells["Department"].Value = dept;

        }

        dataGrid.Refresh();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGrid.Columns) {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGrid.DataSource = distinct;
```

this code It should be placed after:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(vendor);
```

this way:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(vendor);

dataGrid.DataSource = null;
dataGrid.DataSource = distinct;
```

### Edited

For me it works perfectly as follows:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

column.Name = "new";
column.HeaderText = "New";
column.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
column.DisplayIndex = 2;

datagridview1.Columns.Add(column);


column.DataSource = columnDataSource;

datagridview1.DataSource = null;
datagridview1.DataSource = dataGridViewDataSource;
datagridview1.Refresh();
```

Comment: And that helps solve the problem of setting the value of the combo box for each row? I switched up this part like you said and the change is that the department column is now the first column, and when it loads the first combo box is opened up with the correct value selected. Any idea how to just make it set all rows without opening?

Comment: try: DroppedDown = false;